# UseEffect Unexpected Reserved Word 'await'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to convert my class component to a function component. I believe instead of `ComponentDidMount` we need to use `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const {
    data: ServerResponse
  } = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tweets/')
  console.log(ServerResponse)

  setPosts(ServerResponse)

}, [])
```

But I get the following error:

```
Unexpected reserved word 'await'
```

Comment: At a glance you appear to be using an `await` inside of a function that isn't tagged with `async`.  I'd be willing to bet if you updated your arrow function with `async` it would resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If your want to use "await" keyword inside a function you 1st need to decorate that function with "async" keyword.
2. But useEffect hook doesn't expect a promise to be returned from the callback we pass to it.

**Solution:**

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const getData = async () => {
    const { data: ServerResponse } = await axios.get(
      "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tweets/"
    );
    console.log(ServerResponse);

    setPosts(ServerResponse);
  };
  getData();
}, []);
```